# Function call and code in function give different result

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

There is a bug in my program and I am trying to debug it using the debug tool of Pycharm with evaluate expression. I came across the reason my code isn't working, but don't understand how something like this can happen. When I call my function marginalizedTransition with some arguments I get 1.0 as a result, however when I run the code inside that function with the argument put in their place I get 0.00101001196095. These should however be identical as it is identical code.
`player = 1`, `world.amountOfPlayers() = 2` and `world.amountOfPossibleActions = 5`.

```
marginalizedTransitionTest(Ps, [(3, 1), (5, 1)], [(2, 1), (5, 1)], 0, world, 1)
```

where

```
def marginalizedTransitionTest(Ps, sis, sfs, action, world, player):
    otherPlayers = filter(lambda x: x != player, range(world.amountOfPlayers()))
    return sum(np.prod([Ps[otherPlayer][tuple(it.chain(*sis))]
                   [np.insert(actions, player, action)[otherPlayer]]
                   for otherPlayer in otherPlayers])
           for actions in it.product(range(world.amountOfPossibleActions), repeat=world.amountOfPlayers() - 1))
```

gives 4.05514478458 and

```
sum(np.prod([Ps[otherPlayer][tuple(it.chain(*[(3, 1), (5, 1)]))]
               [np.insert(actions, 1, 0)[otherPlayer]]
               for otherPlayer in filter(lambda x: x != 1, range(world.amountOfPlayers()))])
       for actions in it.product(range(world.amountOfPossibleActions), repeat=world.amountOfPlayers() - 1))
```

gives 1.0.

I don't know if this is a common problem. If you need more information concerning the used functions, I can provide them, but this post is already getting ugly.

Comment: Hi, can you please post (as an edit) the values for `word.amountOfPlayers()`, `word.amountOfPossibleActions` and `player` so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: The player variable is 1, the world.amountOfPlayers() is 2 and the world.amountOfPossibleActions is 5. I have also edited the post to include this information. Also, Ps is a 6 dimensional matrix.

Comment: That's great. Can you also post what `PS` is? Also what `world.joinedTransition` is?

Comment: world.joinedTransition is a function with a lot of if-statement and returns either 1, 0 or 0.5.

Comment: Can you check if it returns the same value if you run in in the function and standalone? And what is the value it returns?

Comment: world.joinedTransition gives 0 for every possibilty of actions except (3,). So, for (0,), (1,), (2,) and (4,) you get 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198878/discussion-between-tituszban-and-emiel-lanckriet).

Comment: "this post is already getting ugly" => may I suggest that the reason for this is that your code itself is, indeed, pretty ugly and actually totally unreadable, which really doesn't help with debugging ? Chaining and nesting function calls, list/generator expressions etc may look "smart" but experienced programmers will prefer to decompose this in simple statements with intermediate variables so the code is easy to read and easy to trace.

Comment: Oh and yes; please post a proper [mcve].

Comment: I am aware that my code is ugly, but there do not seem to be any meaning further decompositions, this is actually a fairly simple function that is made ugly by trying to be generalize it. As for a minimally working example I do not understand the problem enough to provide one right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the behavior of `filter` as an iterator. In the function you first create the iterator, than you run a `for` multiple times on it. However, if you try running just this:

```
otherPlayers = filter(lambda x: x != player, range(world.amountOfPlayers()))
for player in otherPlayers:
    print(f'1: {player}')
for player in otherPlayers:
    print(f'2: {player}')
```

The result will be:

```
1: 0
1: 1
```

As you can see, once you've ran a for over the filter, it's exhausted, and won't return anything.
You didn't do the same thing when ran it raw, so the iterator worked as intended.
Because of this, the fix is simple: add the filter in the `for`:

```py
def marginalizedTransition(Ps, sis, sfs, action, world, player):
    return sum(world.joinedTransition(sis, sfs, np.insert(actions, player, action)) *
               np.prod([Ps[otherPlayer][tuple(it.chain(*sis))][np.insert(actions, player, action)[otherPlayer]]
                        for otherPlayer in filter(lambda x: x != player, range(world.amountOfPlayers()))])
               for actions in it.product(range(world.amountOfPossibleActions), repeat=world.amountOfPlayers() - 1))
```

Alternatively, as you've pointed it out in chat, you can just convert the iterator into a list:

```
def marginalizedTransition(Ps, sis, sfs, action, world, player):
    otherPlayers = list(filter(lambda x: x != player, range(world.amountOfPlayers())))
    return sum(world.joinedTransition(sis, sfs, np.insert(actions, player, action)) *
               np.prod([Ps[otherPlayer][tuple(it.chain(*sis))][np.insert(actions, player, action)[otherPlayer]]
                        for otherPlayer in otherPlayers])
               for actions in it.product(range(world.amountOfPossibleActions), repeat=world.amountOfPlayers() - 1))
```

For SO users who want to reproduce the issue, I've created these dummy objects based on chat discussion, and deconstructed the comprehension like so:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as it


class World:
    amountOfPossibleActions = 5

    def amountOfPlayers(self):
        return 2

    def joinedTransition(self, a, b, insert):
        return 1 if insert[0] == 3 else 0


world = World()
player = 1

Ps = {0: {(3, 1, 5, 1): [[0.055144784579474179], [0.055144784579474179], [0.055144784579474179], [0.055144784579474179],
                         [0.055144784579474179]]}}


def marginalizedTransition(Ps, sis, sfs, action, world, player):
    otherPlayers = filter(lambda x: x != player, range(world.amountOfPlayers()))
    s = 0
    for actions in it.product(range(world.amountOfPossibleActions), repeat=world.amountOfPlayers() - 1):
        w = world.joinedTransition(sis, sfs, np.insert(actions, player, action))
        a = []
        for otherPlayer in otherPlayers:
            b = np.insert(actions, player, action)[otherPlayer]
            v = Ps[otherPlayer][tuple(it.chain(*sis))][b]
            a.append(v)
        p = np.prod(a)
        s += w * p
    return s
```

***On a personal note:*** List comprehension is great, it makes code really compact. However, it can make it really difficult to read and debug code. Keep that in mind next time you want to nest comprehension. I was only able to find out what's wrong, after deconstructing it as seen above.